# Subtração de arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, operadores, while

Tenho dois *arrays*: A E B

```
A = [1,2,3...]
B = [7,5,1...]
```

Quando faço essa subtração tem o retorno correto da subtração:

```
console.log(A[0] - B[0]);
```

Porém quando jogo no laço não funciona:

```
while (i = 0) {
    A[i] - B[i]
}
```

Comment: Você quer subtrair cada posição do Array A pelo B ou você quer retirar todos os valores que tem em B do Array A?

Comment: Subtrair os valores do array A com o B

Comment: Seria tipo criar um outro Array tipo C e nele por os valores de A-B? 
C1= A1-B1; C2=A2-B2...

Comment: Vi agora que você fez uma edição incluindo um laço While que tento fazer, você precisa armazenar o resultado em um terceiro Array nesse caso, sua subtração deve estar ocorrendo corretamente, mas não está inserindo o valor resultante em lugar nenhum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos escrever esse código de forma mais organizada, moderna e que evite problemas? E aí vamos consertar os dois erros principais nele. Sempre use `var` para declarar variáveis (ou `let`).

Está atribuindo dentro da condição, não pode (de forma geral), faça a atribuição antes de entrar no laço, e vai até criar complicadores para entrar no laço. Não está incrementando `i`, então ele não sairia do mesmo elemento, e entrando no laço nunca sairia. Sem falar que só subtrair está fazendo nada útil, ou você guarda em uma variável, ou você manda imprimir para ter alguma utilidade.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [7, 5, 1];
var i = 0;
while (i < 3) console.log(a[i] - b[i++]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Subtraction.js).

Este código funciona, está correto, mas não é robusto, não é genérico, resolve só este caso. Fiz assim para não criar confusão com conceitos novos ou apresentar outra forma de resolver o problema. Usei só o `i++` ali para fazer o incremento. Geralmente quando tem essa necessidade usa-se o [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) no lugar do `while`.

Um adendo para iniciante. A outra resposta mostra coisas bastante curiosas e até interessantes para uso em alguns cenários, mas não é algo necessário (nem vi se está certo), é ineficiente e complica a solução para quem sequer domina a sintaxe básica e controle de algoritmos.

Comment: De acordo, concordo que acabei não levando em consideração o nível de aprendizado de quem perguntou baseado no tipo de pergunta. Realmente no caso de iniciantes a sua solução se torna mais viável, até para compreensão.

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel pode não ser a melhor abordagem para um iniciante, mas ainda é válido. Mais opções de resposta é sempre interessante.

Comment: Muito, Obrigado seguirei com os estudos para evoluir :D

Answer (score 3):

Tem duas opções viáveis, a primeira, e que acredito ser melhor e mais "clean" é com a função map():

```
var resultado = A.map(function(element, index) {
    return element - B[index];
});
```

A função [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) percorre cada posição do seu array e retorna um valor após processar o que estiver dentro da função de callback. O parâmetro 'element' se refere ao valor que ele está acessando no momento e o 'index' à posição.

Caso ainda não tenha aprendido ou não esteja habituado a utilizar as funções [map(), filter() e reduce()](https://medium.com/@osuissa/javascript-quando-usar-map-filter-ou-reduce-31aa10e33e9), você também pode fazer dessa forma:

```
A.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  array[index] = element - B[index];
})
```

A função [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) também percorre todo o array A, seria como um For, só que no for você define quantas iterações você quer que sejam feitas, o forEach percorre sempre o número total de posições do Array (a menos que você manipule isso).

Comment: Muito, Obrigado ajudou bastante me apresentando essa função .map gostei mt!!